# Programmatically set connectionString for ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-membership

One can use

```
  new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,null)
```

without providing any connection strings for the Active Directory.

When using `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` you must provide an LDAP endpoint in `web.config`.

The site I'm working on will be deployed on multiple sites and I don't want to have to fill the details in the `web.config` for each deplyoment.

[How To: Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory in Multiple Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx) on MSDN specifies 3 (!) membership providers to deal with 3 domains which is not impressive. However, this article is from 2005 and it deals with a different tasks then what I'm after.

**The question:**

Is is possible to use `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` in a way that the LDAP end point is not hard-coded in the web.config?

I would prefer to use `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` rather than `PrincipalContext` to have (potentially) the ability to call `ChangePassword` etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to use `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` without specifying a target LDAP server.

The connection string must be specified, and the string must contain a server (contains [`ADS_FORMAT_SERVER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

> You must create a connectionStrings Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)
>   entry in the Web.config file that identifies the Active Directory
>   server, Active Directory domain, or ADAM application partition to use.
>   The provider **will only operate at domain scope**, or in a subscope
>   within a domain.

If you want to support an active directory forest, and losing forms authentication is an option, consider using Windows Authentication.  Windows Authentication will use NTLM and Kerberos to get the user's identity within a forest, and you can still change a users password via impersonation.  See [`WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: "..in a way that the LDAP end point is not hard-coded in the web.config?"

Comment: @user2864740, I'm not sure I understand the question.  Windows Authentication does not require an LDAP endpoint to be specified in web.config, and I explicitly say it is not possible with `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`.